# Select date From HTML datepicker with VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Dears,

With the below code i m trying to change datepicker date but i m receiving an error. if you can provide any solution/correction i ll be happy.

@QHarr i m trying to follow an example given by you before few months.

Thanks a lot for your attention.

```
Sub Download_Historical_Data()

Dim DateToUse As String, ChampionName As String

Dim IE As InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument, games As Object
Dim i As Long, j As Long

'Loop until you reach the day before today
Do Until wsControl.Range("B1").Value = Format$(Date - 1, "DD-MM")
    'Initialize project. Check the LastDate and if it is null we use "2018 - 01 - 01" and import the it in wsControl.Range("B1").Value
    If wsControl.Range("B1").Value = "" Then
        DateToUse = Format$("01-01-2018", "DD-MM")
        wsControl.Range("B1").Value = DateToUse
    Else
        DateToUse = Format(wsControl.Range("B1").Value + 1, "DD-MM")
    End If

    'Open Browser and download data
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("https://www.xscores.com/soccer/livescores/" & DateToUse)

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set doc = .document

    End With

    Set games = doc.getElementsByClassName("game_table")

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: A guess: `doc.querySelector("#datepicker * [value=" & DateToUse & "]").Click`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout thanks for the quick respond.i used this line of code before and i receive an error. 
"Could not complete the operation due to error 8070000c"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long method:**

This piece navigates by clicking months  (back arrow) and dates (by looping dates in calendar and selecting appropriate date)

You can only directly select dates up to 2 weeks prior to current date by website design. I have added a hack to get around this at the very end, which makes element selectable, but sadly any date earlier than two weeks before will default return latest date data.

```
Option Explicit  
Public Sub DateSelection()
    'Max past date is 2 weeks prior to today's date
    Dim dateToUse As String, lastSundayPriorMonth As Long, numberOfIndicesToIgnore As Long
    dateToUse = "2018-09-28"

    If Not IsDateValid(dateToUse) Then
        MsgBox "Please select a date between " & Format$(DateAdd("ww", -2, Date) + 1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " and " & Format$(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    lastSundayPriorMonth = GetLastSunday(DateAdd("m", -1, CDate(dateToUse)))
    numberOfIndicesToIgnore = Abs(CDate(dateToUse) - lastSundayPriorMonth) '<==Dates from prior month to ignore on displayed calendar

    Dim dates As Object, ie As InternetExplorer, i As Long
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.xscores.com/soccer/livescores"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document

            Dim numberOfMonthsInPast As Long

            numberOfMonthsInPast = GetNumberOfMonthsBack(dateToUse)

            .querySelector(".dateDetails").Click

            If numberOfMonthsInPast > 0 Then               
                For i = 1 To numberOfMonthsInPast 'navigate back the required number of months
                    .querySelector(".calendar-prev").Click
                    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                Next
            End If

            Set dates = .querySelectorAll(".calendar-dates [class^=date]") '<== All dates in selected month view

            For i = numberOfIndicesToIgnore To dates.Length - 1
                If CInt(dates.item(i).innerText) = Day(dateToUse) Then
                    dates.item(i).querySelector("a").Click 
                    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            'other code
        End With
        Stop                                     '<==Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastSunday(ByVal dateString As String) As Long
    Dim d As Date
    d = DateSerial(YEAR(dateString), Month(dateString) + 1, 1) - 1
    GetLastSunday = d - Weekday(d) + 1
End Function

Public Function IsDateValid(ByVal dateString As String) As Boolean
    IsDateValid = (DateDiff("ww", dateString, Date) >= 0 And DateDiff("ww", dateString, Date) <= 2)
End Function

Public Function GetNumberOfMonthsBack(ByVal dateString As String) As Long
    GetNumberOfMonthsBack = DateDiff("m", dateString, Date)
End Function
```

---

**Preferred:**

I do still seem to be able to get older dates by simply using the `dd-mm` in the URL but I appreciate this seems to produce variable results for you (oft defaulting to latest data).

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.xscores.com/soccer/livescores/19-09"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Stop '<== Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

**Data from today 2018-10-03 (top rows):**

[image]

**Date for manual selection for 2018-09-19 (top rows):**

[image]

**Result of code run for 2018-09-19:**

[image]

---

**Hack-a-round:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DateSelection()
    'Max past date is 2 weeks prior to today's date
    Dim dateToUse As String, lastSundayPriorMonth As Long, numberOfIndicesToIgnore As Long
    dateToUse = "2018-09-18"

    lastSundayPriorMonth = GetLastSunday(DateAdd("m", -1, CDate(dateToUse)))
    numberOfIndicesToIgnore = Abs(CDate(dateToUse) - lastSundayPriorMonth) '<==Dates from prior month to ignore on displayed calendar

    Dim dates As Object, ie As InternetExplorer, i As Long
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.xscores.com/soccer/livescores"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document

            Dim numberOfMonthsInPast As Long

            numberOfMonthsInPast = GetNumberOfMonthsBack(dateToUse)

            .querySelector(".dateDetails").Click

            If numberOfMonthsInPast > 0 Then
                For i = 1 To numberOfMonthsInPast 'navigate back the required number of months
                    .querySelector(".calendar-prev").Click
                    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                Next
            End If

            Set dates = .querySelectorAll(".calendar-dates [class^=date]") '<== All dates in selected month view

            For i = numberOfIndicesToIgnore To dates.Length - 1
                If CInt(dates.item(i).innerText) = Day(dateToUse) Then
                    If Not IsDateWithin2Weeks(dateToUse) Then
                        With dates.item(i)
                            .outerHTML = Replace(dates.item(i).outerHTML, " disabled", vbNullString)
                            Set dates = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".calendar-dates [class^=date]") '<== All dates in selected month view
                        End With
                    End If
                    dates.item(i).querySelector("a").Click

                    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            'other code
        End With
        Stop                                     '<==Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function IsDateWithin2Weeks(ByVal dateString As String) As Boolean
    IsDateWithin2Weeks = (DateDiff("ww", dateString, Date) >= 0 And DateDiff("ww", dateString, Date) <= 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Dear @QHarr i have also proceed to the addition of the date at the end of the URL and does not work.

Comment: the links you post above work fine.but when i use this:
.Navigate ("https://www.xscores.com/soccer/livescores/" & Format(DateToUse, "DD-MM")) 
the date at the datepicker chance put shows today games instead of 01/01/2018.

Comment: @Harr i have edit the code above.that s my final correction and still the data picker show the correct date (as DateToUse)  but the results are today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181150/discussion-between-aloxaz-and-qharr).